# Dots with old data points do not get removed

Tags: d3.js

I am working a chart that visualizes data points with dots. I have followed the "update pattern" with enter()/exit()/merge() that I found in d3 tutorials. For some reason old elements do not get removed. Here is sample code.

```
            const dotClass = ".dot" + klass;
            var dots = svg.selectAll(dotClass)
                .data(data);

            dots.exit()
                .remove();

            dots.enter()
                .append("circle")
                .attr("class", dotClass)
                .merge(dots)
                .attr("cx", calculateX)
                .attr("cy", calculateY)
                .attr("r", 5)
                .attr("fill", color)
```

Any tips would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: You need to select elements with the class dotClass: the selector needs a period before it: selectAll("."+dotClass)

Comment: dotClass is equal to ".dot" + klass. It does have period in front of it.

Comment: Sorry, missed that - `.dotKlass` is not a valid class name if I recall correctly, but either way, you can't use the same string to both select with selectAll and assign class, the selector needs a dot prefixed otherwise you'll be trying to select the wrong thing, as your answer notes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue. It stems from this piece of code `.attr("class", dotClass)` while `dotClass` is equal to `.dotklass` rather than `dotklass` as it should be. (klass is actually a variable but lets assume it equals `klass`. So what happens is that I add new dots with class `.dotklass` and I am looking for class `dotklass` which does not match it.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the problem with class pointed by @Andrew Reid, your code should clearly follow the **enter/exit pattern**.

I suggest to separate `enter`, `merge` and `exit` calls to make it clear:

```
const className = "...your full class name here...";
const dots = svg.selectAll(`.${className}`).data(data);

const newDots = dots.enter()
  .append("circle")
  .classed(className, true);

const updatedDots = newDots.merge(dots);
updatedDots
  .attr("cx", calculateX)
  .attr("cy", calculateY)
  .attr("r", 5)
  .attr("fill", color)

dots.exit().remove();
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not seem to change anything. I still have the problem of old dots not being removed.

Comment: Can you post a working snippet or a link to a fiddle?